# Which one is better, a matter of urgency, or simply urgency?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

> It becomes a matter of urgency to establish the accountability of the
>   public officials.
>
> It becomes an urgency to establish the accountability of the public
>   officials.

Which one is better? I think “a matter of urgency” is both redundant and unclear.

Comment: If it is unclear to you, you should avoid it. However, the context apparently refers to *a matter of urgency*, not *urgency*.

Comment: You might like to visit [ell.se] and go through some of the interesting questions there.

Comment: In your second example, substitute  “is urgent” for “becomes an urgency”

Answer (score 2):

*Urgency* is an abstract noun.  This means that it expresses an abstract concept, similar to wisdom, information, or happiness.  One cannot have *an* urgency in the same way that one cannot have *a* happiness, or two happinesses, or three.

'A matter of urgency' is thus more logical than 'an urgency', but, at least to my ears, 'an urgent matter' is better than either.